# Can't build pango applications. Pango header not found

Tags: make, cairo, pango

I am following [this](http://x11.gp2x.de/personal/google/) tutorial for writing pango applications. When I try to compile it, the compiler can't find the pangocairo.h headers. Here's my source file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pango/pangocairo.h>

void rendertext(cairo_t *cr);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    cairo_t *cr;                                // cairo instance
    cairo_status_t status;                          // variable to hold the various states of the cairo lib
    cairo_surface_t *surface;                       // the cairo surface to render to

    surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32, 300, 100);    // cairo_image_surface_create(pixelformat, width, height);
    cr = cairo_create(surface);                     // tell the cairo instance 'cr' to output to 'surface'
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);                // sets the drawing colour to white
    cairo_paint(cr);                            // fill the surface with the active colour (if you don't do this, you will
                                        // be given a surface with a transparent background to draw on)

    rendertext(cr);                             // do pango stuff here

    cairo_destroy(cr);                          // free the cairo instance
    status = cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "out.png");        // output the contents of 'surface' to the file "out.png"
    cairo_surface_destroy(surface);                     // free the surface
    if (status != CAIRO_STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        // if 'status' was not set to indicate a successful operation when saving as a png, error
        printf("Could not save to png, \"out.png\"\n");
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void rendertext(cairo_t *cr) {
    PangoLayout *layout;                            // layout for a paragraph of text
    PangoFontDescription *desc;                     // this structure stores a description of the style of font you'd most like

    cairo_translate(cr, 10, 20);                        // set the origin of cairo instance 'cr' to (10,20) (i.e. this is where
                                        // drawing will start from).
    layout = pango_cairo_create_layout(cr);                 // init pango layout ready for use
    pango_layout_set_text(layout, "Hello World!", -1);          // sets the text to be associated with the layout (final arg is length, -1
                                        // to calculate automatically when passing a nul-terminated string)
    desc = pango_font_description_from_string("Sans Bold 12");      // specify the font that would be ideal for your particular use
    pango_layout_set_font_description(layout, desc);            // assign the previous font description to the layout
    pango_font_description_free(desc);                  // free the description

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                // set the colour to blue
    pango_cairo_update_layout(cr, layout);                  // if the target surface or transformation properties of the cairo instance
                                        // have changed, update the pango layout to reflect this
    pango_cairo_show_layout(cr, layout);                    // draw the pango layout onto the cairo surface

    g_object_unref(layout);                         // free the layout
}
```

Here's the compile error:

```
cc     pangc.c   -o pangc
pangc.c:3:25: fatal error: pango/pango.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pango/pango.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [pangc] Error 1
```

I have already installed the cairo package libcairo2-dev and the pango library libpango1.0-dev. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to tell `cc` where to find the corresponding headers. Using `pkg-config` can help here:

```
cc ./example1.c -o pangc $(pkg-config --cflags --libs pangocairo)
```

If `pkg-config` is not installed, just type:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config
```